# How do I retrieve the length of individual Strings in a set?

Tags: java, list, set

In my current assignment, I have a text file that contains a large number of words which is stored in a List. one of my methods must store all words of a certain (user specified) length from this List into a Set. furthermore, the different lists are placed into two different classes. My question is: How do I retrieve the length of Individual elements in that list? EDIT: here are the complete classes.

File and List are set up like this in the client class, HangmanMain:

// Class HangmanMain is the driver program for the Hangman program.  It reads a
   // dictionary of words to be used during the game and then plays a game with
   // the user.  This is a cheating version of hangman that delays picking a word
   // to keep its options open.  You can change the setting for SHOW_COUNT to see
    // how many options are still left on each turn.

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.io.*;

public class HangmanMain {
public static final String DICTIONARY_FILE = "E:/CSC143/Workspace/Assignment2/src/dictionary.txt";
public static final boolean DEBUG = false; // show words left

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the cse143 hangman game.");
    System.out.println();

    // open the dictionary file and read dictionary into an ArrayList
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(DICTIONARY_FILE));
    List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        dictionary.add(input.next().toLowerCase());
    }

    // set basic parameters
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What length word do you want to use? ");
    int length = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How many wrong answers allowed? ");
    int max = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    // set up the HangmanManager and start the game
    List<String> dictionary2 = Collections.unmodifiableList(dictionary);
    HangmanManager hangman = new HangmanManager(dictionary2, length, max);
    if (hangman.words().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No words of that length in the dictionary.");
    } else {
        playGame(console, hangman);
        showResults(hangman);
    }
}

// Plays one game with the user
public static void playGame(Scanner console, HangmanManager hangman) {
    while (hangman.guessesLeft() > 0 && hangman.pattern().contains("-")) {
        System.out.println("guesses : " + hangman.guessesLeft());
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println(hangman.words().size() + " words left: "+ hangman.words());
        }
        System.out.println("guessed : " + hangman.guesses());
        System.out.println("current : " + hangman.pattern());
        System.out.print("Your guess? ");
        char ch = console.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        if (hangman.guesses().contains(ch)) {
            System.out.println("You already guessed that");
        } else {
            int count = hangman.record(ch);
            if (count == 0) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, there are no " + ch + "'s");
            } else if (count == 1) {
                System.out.println("Yes, there is one " + ch);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Yes, there are " + count + " " + ch+ "'s");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// reports the results of the game, including showing the answer
public static void showResults(HangmanManager hangman) {
    // if the game is over, the answer is the first word in the list
    // of words, so we use an iterator to get it
    String answer = hangman.words().iterator().next();
    System.out.println("answer = " + answer);
    if (hangman.guessesLeft() > 0) {
        System.out.println("You beat me");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you lose");
    }
}
}
```

my method is set up as such in the HangmanManager class.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class HangmanManager {
private List<String> dictionary;
private int length;
private int max;    
private Set<String> w = new HashSet<String>();
private SortedSet<Character> guess;

Integer L1 = new Integer(length);
public HangmanManager (List<String> dictionary, int length, int max){
    this.dictionary = dictionary;
    this.length = length;
    this.max = max;
}
public Set<String> words (){

    while (scan.hasNext()){
        if (scan.next().equals(L1)){
            w.add(scan.next());
        }
    }
    return w;

}

public int guessesLeft(){

    return max;

}

public SortedSet <Character> guesses(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    return guess;

}

public String pattern(){
    return null;

}

public int record (char guess){
    return guess;

}



}
```

the Scan is just a placeholder name. As you can see in the first block, the while loop adds all the strings in the DICTIONARY_FILE in the "dictionary" list. What I want to do in the second block is add all the words of a certain length into the w list but I don't know how to read the file from a completely different class (if that's even possible) and I also don't know how to take the length of each individual element in said file. do you guys have any ideas? or do you need me to upload more info.

PS: the full title of my assignment is "Evil Hangman." From what I've looked up, its a fairly common programming assignment so you should be able to google it and get more info on what I mean.

PSS: don't mind the other methods in HangmanManager. I'm mostly focused on the "Words" method.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please don't forget to tag the programming language you are using. I removed the eclipse tag and added java; as the question is not suited for the eclipse tag.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so assuming you have the list with all the words set up, here is some pseudocode to guide you forwards.

```
for every string in set
   check if word is of specified length
      if true:
        add word to set
      if false:
        do nothing
```

[String api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) might have some useful methods for this, especially for determining the length of the string.. :)

About the latter part of your question, it is somewhat hard to answer how to access things in another class without more code to see how it is set up. Generally, you use a getter method to retrieve the field.

Comment: when you say "set up the list" do you mean place it in the client class or the support class?

Comment: You can access it from either, but without seeing more complete code, it isn't really possible to help with that part

Comment: I was hoping to avoid making a huge post like my previous questions but I guess too long is better than too short. I'll post the complete classes in a minute.

Comment: That might not be necessary, but some more information is needed. Are you creating instances of the classes? Or is everything in the classes static?

Comment: @Sol420 as far as I can see, you calling the method there just fine, so the latter part of your question seems a bit moot :)

Comment: I'm supposed to create an instance in the client class (HangmanMain). The user enters a specific length and the supporting class (HangmanManager) chooses all words of that length for use in the game.

Comment: Yes. You are already passing a list of words to the words() method, why you are trying to use scanner there?

Comment: so wait, everything I said I was trying to do has already been done by the code in the HangmanMain class? As in, it already creates the list of words with the specified length? all I need to do is add the return statement in the HangmanManager?

Comment: And that leads back to the million dollar question. I know how to filter the word length, I just don't know the syntax for how to get the word length from a document in a completely separate class. that's why I used the scanner  earlier. I just scanned the whole file into the method but I don't think that was what I was supposed to do.

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused. You are passing the list of words to hangmanManager, why can't you process the list there?

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. I don't know how to access the list from HangmanManager. I know the list is passed into the "dictionary" parameter in the hangman object. I just don't know how to access the data I need (i.e the string length) from that parameter. Does that clear things up a bit or am I still not making sense?

Comment: in hangmanManager, just use dictionary.get(i).getLength(); to get word length at index i, dictionary is a field in hangmanManager, and visible in the whole class